# How to tell which UITableCells are selected with a check mark in a Multi Select UITableview. Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, multi-select

I have a UITableview and in that TableView I which populates with json data. I have implemented a multi selected tableview code that checks the touched table cell with a checkmark.

My question is how can I tell which of my tableview cells I have selected and how do I put an action to the selected table view cells?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return self.json2.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
}

cell.textLabel.text = self.json2[indexPath.row][@"SurveyName"];

//cell.detailTextLabel.text = self.json1[indexPath.row][@"AssetDesc"];

// Sets the accessory for the cell
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


if (thisCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

}else{
    thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

}
}

- (UITableViewCellAccessoryType)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//add your own code to set the cell accesory type.
return UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

So normally If I were to make a segue from a tableview cell I would do the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Perform segue
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"showSurveyForm" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showSurveyForm"]) {
    // NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    CameraViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    // Hide bottom tab bar in the detail view
    destViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    destViewController.surveyQuestionId = self.surveyQuestionIDParsed;
    destViewController.jsonTitleforSurvey = self.json2;
    destViewController.surveyTitleAssetId = self.assetSurvey;

    NSLog(@"Survey ID for Survey: %@", self.surveyQuestionIDParsed);
    NSLog(@"Survey name titile: %@", self.json2 );
    NSLog(@"Asset ID for Title: %@", self.assetSurvey);

}

else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showCameraRoll"]) {
    // NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    // Hide bottom tab bar in the detail view
}

else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showJsonData"]) {
    // NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

}

else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"testPickerDemo"]) {
    // NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

}
}
```

I would like to make a segue after choosing the multi selected cells in my UItableview.

e.g I make a selection and 2 rows are checked. I would like to capture or see in my nslog which tableview cells were selected so I can do another json call and segue based on the rows that were selected.

I know how to call and parse json and make a segue.

[image]

Comment: Have you solved the issue ?

Comment: @Vin. Sorry no no yet. I am only getting my ID or array when I press a selected cell. I instead want to use a button and after pushed tell me which rows were selected.

Comment: So what's wrong ? Just add those `indexPath.row` to `selArray` (shown in my Answer) and `-onButtonClick` , you can use that array. Hope you are getting me !!! :)

Comment: Check UPDATE in my Code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath` something like this :

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
        UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString *selStr = [yourSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
--->        NSMutableArray *selArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    //Write this line in viewDidLoad method.
        if (thisCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) 
        {
            thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            [selArray addObject:selStr];
        }
        else
        {
            thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            [selArray removeObject:selStr];
        }
        NSLog(@"selArray :: %@",selArray);
    }
```

**UPDATE :**

It will give you the **Array of textLabel's text of Selected Rows**. Then you can use it in `-yourButtonPressed` method

```
- (IBAction)yourButtonPressed:(id)sender;
{
    NSLog(@"selArray :: %@",selArray);
}
```

GoodLuck !!!

Comment: Thanks, But it logs only the ID of last cell that I pressed not all the cells that were was selected at the time i pushed the button?

Comment: @BlakeLoizides: Write that 3rd line in viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Wow. That did the trick. Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it as you have helped me in a big way. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, what if I also want to remember the states that were unchecked after they were checked. I do this to objects received from the server and some of them needs to be checked. However, if they are unchecked now, I need to know this, so that I can use a different function based on the checked/unchecked state. Thanks!